# Lucene - Which analyzer to use to avoid prepositions

Tags: lucene

I am using the Lucene standard analyzer to parse text. however, it is returning prepositions as well as words like "i", "the", "and" etc...
Is there an Analyzer I can use that will not return these words?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[StandardAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html) uses [StopFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/StopFilter.html).

By default the words in the [STOP_WORDS_SET](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html#STOP_WORDS_SET) are excluded.  If this is not sufficient, there are constructors which allow you to pass in a list of stop words which should be removed from the token stream. You can provide the list using a `File`, a `Set`, or a `Reader`.

Comment: ok thanks for that. If I want to pass in my own words, do you know of a list of words that say Google will not index? or any other search engine for that matter. I had a look around but couldn't find anything. Thanks again

Comment: @Joeblackdev Hmm...sorry, I don't know of such a list.

Comment: Actually, Google doesn't omit these types of words. An excellent example of this is go Google the band "The The".